# I wrote a gateway with Ocelot to my API that I wrote with .Net. However, I want to convert this Http Request Gateway to WebSocket

Tags: c#, .net, request, api-gateway, ocelot

**This is my regular Http Request** :

```
  
{
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/User/GetList?{page}&{pageSize}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/GetList?PageRequest.Page={page}&PageRequest.PageSize={pageSize}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "{CoreUrl}"

        }
      ]
    },
```

I didn't show details because my Gateway works when I make Http requests.

**When I convert this request type to websocket :**

```
 {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/ws/gateway/User/GetList?{Page}&{PageSize}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/GetList?PageRequest.Page={Page}&PageRequest.PageSize={PageSize}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
           "Host": "{CoreUrl}"

        }
      ],
    },
```

But when I convert this request type to websocket . I can send a request to the gateway. Then the debug I put in my Api method works and the data is returned regularly and without errors. But after postman connect, the only returned error is "Internal Server"

**This is Postman Response :**

> Could not connect to localhost:5030/ws/gateway/User/GetList?PageRequest.Page=0&PageRequest.PageSize=10
>
> 15:11:26
>
> Error: Unexpected server response: 500
>
> ###### Handshake Details
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:5030/ws/gateway/Hero/GetListByHeroType?HeroType=1&PageRequest.Page=0&PageRequest.PageSize=10
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

I checked through the Ocelot documentation.

On the Ocelot site it says that's enough

I wrote the backend codes for WebSocket.

I completely changed Program.cs.

I tested all my Urls by trying them from scratch.